# How to separate the starting column and word of each line into new file

Tags: bash

This is the file I have:

```
serverA.domain.com plan_name: PlanA
serverB.domain.com plan_name: PlanC
serverA.domain.com plan_name: PlanB
serverB.domain.com plan_name: PlanD
```

I want to do this:

> check the first column of this file, and write it (append in fact) to a new file called (serverX) (the name is in fact the first part of FQDN), the whole line.

Example of a file called `serverA`:

```
serverA.domain.com plan_name: PlanA
serverA.domain.com plan_name: PlanB
```

Example of a file called `serverB`:

```
serverB.domain.com plan_name: PlanC
serverB.domain.com plan_name: PlanD
```

I'm googling if that's possible with awk or sed but till now no success.

I'm thinking of a `for` loop but don't know how to save the previous value until the end and how to perform that.

Comment: have you tried `cat file.log | grep serverA > serverA.log` and equivalent for the other one?

Comment: @Verthais thanks, but there are more than 100 names and may contain `A1`, I appreciate your comment but that doesn't work.

Comment: Then I would use `awk` to print 1st collumn pipe it throught `uniq -u` and then write a for loop on top. `for prefix in $(cat file.log | awk '{print $1 }' | uniq -u ); do { cat file.log | grep ${prefix} > "${prefix}.log" }; done;` - there seem to be a better solutino in the answer.

Comment: @Verthais `cat file.log | grep ...` is a famous anti-pattern. `grep ... file.log` is much more natural.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet that's true, however it's hard to un-learn it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this out :

```
awk '{print > substr($1, 1, index($1, ".")-1)}' your_file.txt
```

for example, if your input file contains:

```
serverA.domain.com plan_name: PlanA
serverB.domain.com plan_name: PlanC
serverA.domain.com plan_name: PlanB
serverB.domain.com plan_name: PlanD
```

the `awk` will create two output files: `serverA` and `serverB` and the contents of `serverA` will be:

```
serverA.domain.com plan_name: PlanA
serverA.domain.com plan_name: PlanB
```

good luck !

Comment: how/where do you learn this kind of things with `awk`?

Comment: A bit simpler: `awk -F. '{print > $1}' your_file.txt` (declare dot as the field separator, print-append each line to the file named as first field).

Comment: @Verthais just participating in online communities like stackoverflow and  linux stackexchange 

Comment: @Verthais If you suspect that `awk` is a tool that you will frequently use, reading the [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) is probably a good idea.